# Format dd/mm/yy to mm/dd/yy in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am inserting a record into data extension from the form values where I have a date field in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. As Marketing Cloud is not accepting the value in this format, is there any way where we can format the date from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

`MM/dd/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyy` is working.

`%%=Format("03/28/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy")=%%`

Output: `28/03/2017`

I want something like this `dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy`

`%%=Format("28/03/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy")=%%`

Output should be: `03/28/2017`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFMC uses the standard C# date formatting library, so you have to convert the input string to a date first.

```
%%=Format(StringToDate("28/03/2017"), "MM/dd/yyyy")=%%
```

**Output:** 03/28/2017